# Assigning a pre made, rigged model to a Mixamo/collada data

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I cannot figure out how to assign my model, who is rigged with individual bones, to a Mixmo, rigged model. [image: models]

Comment: Have you tried uploading your model directly to mixamo?

Comment: I have, that plum color actually is my model. It was before coloring though, and for some reason, the shoulders droop down. I only need walking for one or two scenes